# alternative to s3fuse for docker container s3 mount

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-s3, s3fs

I am running application on EKS.I need to access the s3 bucket inside my pod containers. These applications are launched from deployments using service account and WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider. as per documentation s3 fuse only accepts the standard AWS credentials file. Due to security issues , its risky to provide credentials while building image and also not feasible solution.
I am looking out for any cleaner solution for my use.

Comment: You should be able to use an AWS SDK here.  You can't mount a filesystem from inside a container, and if you ask Kubernetes to create a volume out of the mount it wouldn't run with your application-specific credentials.

Answer (score 1):

s3fs supports the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables.

Comment: but while running with service account i cant provide this. My container pods use service account and WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider